# How to create an array of price-ranges from an array of price-values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, range, reduce

I have an array of prices

I would like to group these prices into ranges if they are within 2 of each other

How do I achieve this

```
// present array
const array = [
   '3','5','6','12','17','22'
]

// the result I want
const array_ranges = [
   '3-6', '12',
  '17','22'
]
```

Comment: what goes wrong with **your** code?

Comment: what do you mean by 'within 2'

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+array+by+values+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @lucumt [ask] - we want to see some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an offset of `2` and check the last pair if the delta is greater as this offset and push a new value the result set, otherwise take the value of the first part of the last stored or value and build a new pair.

```js
const
    array = ['3','5','6','12','17','22'],
    offset = 2,
    result = array.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (!i || v - a[i - 1] > offset) r.push(v);
        else r.push(`${r.pop().split('-', 1)[0]}-${v}`);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As terse and unreadable as always, but it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less terse version

```js
const array = ['3', '5', '6', '12', '14', '17', '22'],
  rangeGap = 2,
  arrRange = array.reduce((acc, num) => {
    const range = acc.at(-1).split("-"), last = range.at(-1);
    if ((num - last) <= rangeGap) {
      if (range.length === 1) range.push(num); // new range
      else range[range.length-1] = num; // rewrite last slot
      acc[acc.length-1] = range.join("-"); // save the range
    } else acc.push(num);
    return acc;
  }, [array[0]]); // initialise with first entry
console.log(arrRange)
```

Comment: As verbose and unreadable as always, but it works. ;)

Comment: Ok, shortened it and added comments

Comment: Sorry, was just teasing.  I'm not sure between yours and Nina's which I find more readable.  But neither is strongly more so to me (either before or after your changes.)  Readability is a slippery concept.

Comment: For experienced users perhaps, but I had to read this more than once: `(!i || v - a[i - 1] > offset) ... \`${r.pop().split('-', 1)[0]}-${v}\``

Comment: Right, but there's a continuum.  There are coders who find `map` less readable than a `for`-loop, and probably still some around who find anything more recent than a `JMP` invocation unnecessary frivolity.  My personal style is probably closer to Nina's than to yours, but not particularly close to either.

Comment: @ScottSauyet If I saw your style in a code review, I would ask you to please stop it. It is very chi-chi. A Bit Like Writing Every Word With Capitals... That said [this iffy article is great](https://fr.umio.us/iffy-literals/)

Comment: I'm glad you like the article.  When I do code reviews, I try to ensure that the code matches the style and goals of the team.  For my personal stuff, I write it in a style that appeals to me.  For SO, it's mostly a hybrid: fairly common JS indentation, but with inline whitespace as you see in my answer.  I work hard to use expressions rather than statements and to avoid mutation; I'm a big fan of doing as much FP as I can in JS.

Answer (score 0):

One possible generic, configurable and re-usable  approach was to implement the reducer function as function statement where the initial value is an object of two properties `threshold` and `result` where the former defines a range value's tolerance or delta to its previous/next range value and the latter featuring all created/collected range values.

The reducer does process an array of just number values; therefore a `map` task which assures number values only has to be executed before.

```js
function createAndCollectNumberRanges({ threshold, result }, current, idx, arr) {
  threshold = Math.abs(threshold);

  const previous = arr[idx - 1] ?? null;
  const next = arr[idx + 1] ?? null;

  if (
    previous === null ||
    previous < current - threshold
  ) {
    result.push(String(current));

  } else if (
    (next > current + threshold || next === null) &&
    previous >= current - threshold
  ) {
    result.push(`${ result.pop() }-${ current }`);
  }
  return { threshold, result };
}

console.log(
  ['3', '5', '6', '12', '17', '22']
    .map(Number)
    .reduce(createAndCollectNumberRanges, {

      threshold: 2,
      result: [],

    }).result
);
console.log(
  ['0', '3', '5', '6', '12', '14', '15', '17', '22', '23']  
    .map(Number)
    .reduce(createAndCollectNumberRanges, {

      threshold: 2,
      result: [],

    }).result
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make this more generic in two ways.  First,  it probably *improves* readability to make `2` a parameter so that in other circumstances, you could choose `10` instead, or ten million.

Second, I would build this atop a more generally useful utility function that groups a sequence of values according to the result of a predicate applied pair-wise to the previous element and the most recent one.  Here we would use the predicate `(a, b) => b - a <= 2` (or really, given the above, `(a, b) => b - a <= threshold`.)

It could look like this:

```js
const push = (x) => (xs) => ((xs .push (x)), xs)

const groupWhen = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((r, x, i, a) => i == 0 || !pred (a [i - 1], x)
    ? push ([x]) (r)
    : ((push (x) (r .at (-1))), r),
  []
)

const groupCloseNumbers = (threshold) => (numbers) =>
  groupWhen ((a, b) => b - a <= threshold) (numbers .sort ((a, b) => a - b))
    .map (ns => ns .length == 1 ? ns [0] : `${ns .at (0)}-${ns .at (-1)}`)


console .log (groupCloseNumbers (2) (['3','5','6','12','17','22'])) 
  //=> ["3-6", "12", "17", "22"]
```

**`push`** is a trivial helper, pushing the value onto an array, returning that array.

Our utility function is **`groupWhen`**; it continually adds values to the current group so long as our predicate returns true, creating a new group when it's false.  Using this with our predicate, we'll get a result like  `[["3", "5", "6"], ["12"], ["17"], ["22"]]`.

Our main function, `groupCloseNumbers`, numerically sorts the values (if you know they're coming in already sorted, you can skip this step), calls `groupWhen`, and then maps over the results, to list single values as is and longer lists as ranges.

And if I was feeling that this was still not clear, I would look at several more helper functions, perhaps some or all of these:

```js
const withinDistance = (threshold) => (a, b) => b - a <= threshold
const sortNumerically = (ns) => ns .sort ((a, b) => a - b)
const asRange = (ns) => `${ns .at (0)}-${ns .at (-1)}`
const valueOrRange = (ns) => ns .length == 1 ? ns [0] : asRange (ns)

const groupCloseNumbers = (threshold) => (numbers) =>
  groupWhen (withinDistance (threshold)) (sortNumerically (numbers))
    .map (valueOrRange)
```

But that's up to the developer and the developer's team, not me.

Comment: [`${ns .at (0)}-${ns .at (-1)}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) - never used that one - is it the prettifier that splits them all like that? Or just you who writes dot notation like "no - one" else I know

Comment: `at` is really nice for `at (-1)`, much better than `slice (-1) [0]`  The other one here is just for consistency; it could just as easily be `ns [0]`.  The dot spacing is all me, an idiosyncratic style borrowed originally from @user633183, who gave it up soon after, but which I really appreciate for focusing on method calls.

Comment: I hate it ;).....

Comment: @mplungjan: If you're talking about the spacing, that surprises me not at all.  If it's `at`, I'm curious why.

Comment: The spacing. I would never "hate" a JS method other than "substr" ;)

Comment: Actually I see the support is good enough that I now will use it too. `arr.at(-1)` is so much cleaner than `arr[arr.length-1]` - too bad we cannot use it in assignment: `arr.at(-1) = newLastValue`

Comment: @mplungjan: I don't have a great relationship with `Array.prototype.splice`, and the keyword `with` is an abomination.  A very interesting language, but more than a normal share of warts as well, I think.

Comment: Never used with. Completely agree. I have loved JS since I started using it in the mid '90s

Comment: @mplungjan: Since '98 for me.  Haven't always loved it; and there are times when I was sure it *hated* me.  But it's been a fun ride.